# SQLCMD : Can we put double quotation mark to output file ?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3, sqlcmd

May I ask is there any way to put double quotation mark "" to each columns of the output file exported by SQLCMD, SQL Server 2016 as follows?

```
ex.
"TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3"
"TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3"
```

We'd like to export files for AWS Redshift through S3 bucket.

If there is no approptiate options on SQLCMD, maybe we'd better to verify Invoke-Sqlcmd, PowerShell. 
If you have more better and simple way, any of your advice would be appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried -I in sqlcmd to enable quoted identifiers?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt comment, @Vlam. Unfortunately -I is not working as I expected ... I tried -I in my script as follows (maybe something is wrong) ;  sqlcmd -Q "SET NoCount ON; !STR_COMMAND!;" -I -o !OUTPUT_FILE! -u -s, -W -h -1 !CONN_PARAM!

Comment: Is -I working ? Not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I chose PowerShell for this porpose.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $StrQry -ServerInstance $StrSvrName -IgnoreProviderContext | Export-Csv -path $StrExpFile -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Each output file columns are enclosed by "" double quotations as my expectations.

Comment: Unfortunatly this approach has poor performance. Writing a csv that way did need 8 minutes, while the same query using sqlcmd only needed 6 seconds.

Comment: @Andreas Wow, big differences!! Thank you so much for your precious advice:)

Answer (score 3):

For the next person banging their head trying to figure this out. I needed to call a batch file from XP_CMDSHELL which invoked SQLCMD which called a SQL query from a file. Why? Because the query has double quotes surrounding the column names, being dynamically generated, so that comma data in the fields wouldn't interfere with the CSV export process of SQLCMD. (comma delimited). It's as simple as adding -I for quoted identifier. You could then embed your double quoted query in the string or keep feeding it from a file.

***Simple Test:***

*batch file:*

```
 sqlcmd -E -S PGCDWDEV02 -d ANALYTICS -I -i D:\extractH\sqlquery.sql -o D:\output.txt
```

*sql file:*

```
   SELECT "TABLE_NAME" FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

***The real deal put together:***

```
    DECLARE @SQLCMD VARCHAR(4000);
    SET @SQLCMD
         = 'sqlcmd -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' + @db_name + ' -E -I -i ' + 
              @queryFile + ' -o "' + @root_path + ''
                + @object_name + '.csv" -W -w 10000 -s","';
```

Comment: sorry for my late confrimation but thanks for your useful information :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to use `QUOTENAME` function because double quote in sqlserver indicate just column name

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(TEST1, '"'), QUOTENAME(TEST2, '"'), QUOTENAME(TEST3, '"')
    FROM t
```

[more about function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: many thank for your useful information. If I can't find simple option, I will try quotename for each columns! (Since we have a lot of target tables in different columns structure, I'd like to seek something more lazy way :))

Comment: Does it matter to use '"' over CHAR(34)?