# Problem using -sqlcmd parameters in SQL agent job

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Trying to export some data running PowerShell script as agent job.  all works but need data surrounded by double quotes.  here is the end of script, I get my headers hidden and comma delimited by cant get the data surrounded by double quotes (if anyone has a list of parameters for  that would be great
`-sqlcmd   ORDER BY s.name " -s "," -o $instfile  -h -1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLCMD : Can we put double quotation mark to output file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511532/sqlcmd-can-we-put-double-quotation-mark-to-output-file)

Comment: To fix that problem, there are commands that allow T-SQL syntax on the sql command line.

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is when there's no PowerShell code actually included. Are you aware that PowerShell's `Export-Csv` cmdlet includes a `-UseQuotes Always` param?

Comment: so running this as a sql agent job running a powershell command, need to deploy this cant have xp_cmdshell turned on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.